# Is there a way to validate if all environment variables in the code exists in the .env file?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm trying to find a way to validate if all of the environment variables used in the code are actually set in the .env file

Something like a test to run in the pipeline that throw a warning if I'm missing a variable in the environment I'm currently deploying.

Context

Nodejs

It is a big application with a lot of environment variables.

There are multiple environments dev, qa, prod.

I'm using the package **dotenv**

```
dotenv.config()
```

```
process.env.A_VARIABLE
```

Comment: At the point you have your "config" object check for all the keys you want. Maybe create an array of keys to check for..

Comment: I actually have env-template file with an array of keys.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a package targeting exactly this issue: https://github.com/af/envalid

You can define a required schema for the `.env` file; if a condition is not met, it will end the process with a proper error message.

Furthermore, there are nice features like providing default values and loading a sanitized and typesafe env object for further usage in your application.